# how to print pass a link in include using a variable

Tags: php

Hi I have a variable that has the link to my include file. How will I execute this ?

lets use an example

$var = "includes/printALLDogNames.php";

now what I need to do is print

includes "includes/printALLDogNames.php";

when i print include "$a" Or include $a I get an error my php is not so great so any help will help.

Comment: Is it because you're printing `a` instead of `var`?  Can we see your code?

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked the manual for `include`, it suggests that you use the following approach:

```
include 'string/path/to/files.php';
```

So, to use a variable, you'd need to use:

```
include "$var";
```

The above assumes that `$var` holds the path to the file you wish to include. Please note that in your question you assign to the `$var` variable, and then say that:

> when i print include "$a" Or include $a I get an error

`$var` and `$a` are ***not*** equal; they're two separate variables (assuming they're both assigned a value).

Reference:

- [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Answer (score -1):

include($a); should be spot on. If this fails, you might have a wrong value in $a.